# How can I run two or more version of MySql in the ubutnu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, apache2, mysql-8.0, mysql-5.6

I need run one Magento 2 project and one laravel project but both project require diffrent version of MySql. Basically For Laravel I need Mysql 8.x version but for Magento 2 I need 5.6 or 5.7. I've tried to get help from online but not found actually.

Comment: You can use [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) for such a structure.

Comment: I think even chrooting could do the trick